# Enviando vetores do computador para o Arduino

Tags: arduino, array

Olá,

Estou com um projeto que utiliza o Arduino para executar algumas operações para mim.

Entretanto, essas operações utilizam vetores.

Eu preciso de alguma forma de enviar um vetor do computador (sem ser pela Serial) para o Arduino, e depois enviá-lo de volta para o computador.

Alguma sugestão de como fazer?

---

Hm, vamos ver se consigo me explicar melhor. A forma como coloquei foi um pouco fraca. Eu preciso enviar um vetor com suas respectivas entradas, e um número inteiro qualquer pra ser utilizado pra fazer algumas operações com esse vetor. É como se o arduino fizesse um papel de um filtro pra esse vetor, onde ele receberia esse vetor, fizésse algumas mudanças nele, e depois escrevesse um novo vetor.

É apenas o Arduino, sem nenhum shield extra. Há um tempo, eu fiz algo semelhante pra fazer recepção de dados por RFID. Criei um interface em C pra enviar a autorização de início de leitura pelo shield rfid, e então o arduino printava esse ID da tag rfid na interface em c.

Mas nesse caso é somente o Arduino. A solução que eu pensei foi escrever entrada por entrada do vetor:

```
void setup(){

    Serial.begin(9600);
   }    
        byte array[9];
      void loop() {
           if (Serial.available() >= 9){
                 for (int i=0; i <=8 ; i++){
                   array[i] = Serial.read(); 
                 }
                 for (int i=0; i <=8 ; i++){
                 Serial.println(array[i]);
                 }
           }

   }
```

Mas será que teria uma forma de enviar o vetor todo de uma vez só? Pois em alguns momentos os vetores podem ter um número grande de entradas.